# Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /"

Tags: php, symfony4

I just started following a symfony 4 tutorial
I set up the whole project with composer and got the index file showing up in browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/

I'm stuck on the very first Router/Controller/View example
The route is not working properly or at all. I always get a 404 error.

1:

[image]

2:

[image]

3:

[image]

```
<?php


namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController
{
    public function number()
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

```
# the "app_lucky_number" route name is not important yet
app_lucky_number:
  path: /lucky/number
  controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

I'm out of ideas, I've looked everywhere on google and did not found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your contorller is on the right path `src/Controller/`

Example

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class LuckyController extends AbstractController
{

  public function number()
  {
    echo __LINE__;die();
  }
}
```

Check the  `config/routes.php` files have the correct routes

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator;

use App\Controller\LuckyController;

return function (RoutingConfigurator $routes) {
   // Matches /lucky exactly
   $routes->add('lucky_number', '/lucky')
      ->controller([LuckyController::class, 'number'])
   ;

};
```

`OR`

Change your YAML to

```
# the "app_lucky_number" route name is not important yet
app_lucky_number:
path: /lucky
controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

After doing this access this URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/lucky`

Comment: I just noticed I didn't extend from AbstractController but in the end nothing changed. the controller is in that directory and I don't have a routes.php, it's a yaml file and I posted it on post

Comment: Exactly same error, it has to be in the framework itself, as my code is exactly as stated in the tutorial

Comment: @Moelanz what url you are browsing ?

Comment: in your controller inside funtion echo something and access 127.0.0.1:8000/lucky

Comment: Nothing changed at all

Comment: is this your yaml file location config/routes.yaml ?

Comment: Yes it is. In the mean time I restarted the project with a other tutorial. And it seems that there is a bug in the composer download. First project was downloaded from 

composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton

now I did composer create-project symfony/skeleton
Got it working

Answer (score 0):

In your navigator, you need to write "lucky" after 127.0.0.1:800
I have the same matters and it took me 2 hours to fix it